# CodeIgniter - Server - DB connectivity issues

Tags: mysql, database

What would be the solution for error occurred in CodeIgniter  -

> mysqli::real_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: name or service not known ?

This problem does not occur frequently. Is this a coding related erorr or server issues?

Comment: Are you using a DNS name for your config, or an IP? Is the MySQL server on the same machine or a different system?

Comment: I am using DNS name... MYSQL server is on the same machine.

Comment: Could be a DNS resolver issue.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The issue has been resolved , its was a server error it seems.